# How do I connect to SQL Server running inside docker on mac using Python3?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, docker

I want to connect to my SQL Server database running in a Docker container using Python. Currently, I am facing issues with

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

and I have followed the documentation, did everything as mentioned.

I tried using the following connection string:

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=US_NATIONAL_COPY;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'
conn = db.connect(connection_string)
```

This produced the aforementioned result.

It should be noted that my docker exposes on a port number 1401.

When I type the command; `curl localhost:1401`, I get the following result:
`Empty reply from server`.

It should also be noted that I am able to execute SQL queries entering the Docker and running them.

My full code is:

```
import pyodbc as db
import pandas
connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=US_NATIONAL_COPY;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'
conn = db.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

stateQuery = 'select numeric_id, us_state_terr, abbreviation, is_state from states'

cursor.execute(stateQuery)

stateInfo = cursor.fetchall()

# declare a dictionary
stateIsState = {}

for thisState in stateInfo:
    print (thisState[2])
    stateIsState[thisState[2]] = thisState[3]
    stateIsState[thisState[1]] = thisState[3]

datFrame = pandas.read_sql(stateQuery, conn)

for statename in datFrame.us_state_terr:
    print (statename)

def is_it_a_state(stateabbrv):
    if stateabbrv in stateIsState:
        if stateIsState[stateabbrv] == "State":
            return ("yes, " + stateabbrv + " is a state")
        else:
            return ("no, " + stateabbrv + " is not a state")
    else:
        return (stateabbrv + " is not in the dictionary")

print (is_it_a_state('NY'))

print (is_it_a_state('MP'))

print (is_it_a_state('QQ'))
```

The error is at the connection line itself.

## Update

I tried the following [this](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/wiki/Mac-setup-to-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-Server) article. There was a point of diversion: I could not find the unixODBC config files in my Mac. But there was a directory, `/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/<version>/`. Note: as the documentation states that there must be an `etc` directory, there wasn't. So, I created one and created two files inside it: `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini`.
The former one is:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL on Win32
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

The latter one is as follows:

```
[localhost]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = /tmp/sql.log
Database            = US_NATIONAL_COPY
Servername          = localhost:1401
UserName            = SA
Password            = <YourStrong!Passw0rd>
Port                = 1401
Protocol            = 8.0
ReadOnly            = No
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No
```

But then, my command: `isql localhost SA '<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'` failed with the error: `[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect`
What should I do to get connected in this manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft provides a unixODBC compatible driver for SQL Server, available from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).  The full reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

If you're using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), you can:

1. Install unixodbc

```
brew install unixodbc
```

2. Tap into the Microsoft repo

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
```

3. Update and install

```
brew update
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

That might properly install the unixodbc driver in your `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` file (it should, but it's been 50/50 for me).  If it didn't, you can copy the driver config from the msodbcsql17 dir (`/usr/local/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.4.1.1/odbcinst.ini`) into your `odbcinst.ini`

Ultimately, you need a stanza in your `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` file that looks like:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

And your python connection string will look like

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=US_NATIONAL_COPY;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect the DB container from your python container using localhost.

`Localhost` refers to the python container localhost, not the DB container or the Host.

If both are running in the different container then better to use docker-compose so that both containers will be in same network then you can refer the container name in the string.

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        image: python:3.7-alpine3.9
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Now the connection string will be

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=db;DATABASE=US_NATIONAL_COPY;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'
```

If you running SQL server outside of container then you can refer the Host SQL server using Host IP inside python container.

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=YOUR_HOST_IP;DATABASE=US_NATIONAL_COPY;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'
```

YOUR_HOST_IP is not the localhost but the ip of the local network.

Comment: My Python is running on my mac, and the sql server is running inside the docker container named "sql1". How do I connect to that?

Comment: If port is publish that you can connect using `localhost:port`

Comment: Yes, port is published.

Comment: So, I am still getting this error[2] even after using the connection string[1].

[1]: `connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost:1401;DATABASE=US_NATIONAL_COPY;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>'`

[2]`>>> conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Comment: So, this is the context. https://pastebin.com/2Y8sPT8h

Again, thank you so much!