# Trying to connect to SQL Server in Docker from external Python

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I created the following Docker image following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVNWRYPv78o:

```
docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
docker run -d --name sql_server_name -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=YourPassword123' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Now I want to try to access the server from a local Python script.
Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088919/6131111
I do:

```
brew install unixodbc
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

My `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` file looks like this:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

To know my server I do:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' sql_server_name
172.17.0.2
```

In the python script I create the connection string as:

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=172.17.0.2;DATABASE=WideWorldImportersDW;UID=sa;PWD=YourPassword123'
```

I have previously imported WideWorldImportersDW to my databases as can be seen here:

[image]

But I am getting:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: `172.17.0.2` is the instance's IP address inside the Docker virtual network. Your `-p 1433:1433` parameter indicates that you've mapped your localhost's tcp/1433 port to the instance's tcp/1433 port so your Python connect string (running on the macOS host itself) should be using `...;SERVER=localhost,1433;...`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using my local IP address as server:

```
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.1.47,1433;DATABASE=WideWorldImportersDW;UID=sa;PWD=YourPassword123'
```